# ActiveRecord create! with Postgresql saves Boolean as 't', but updates to 1/0 after update/save

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, boolean

Using ActiveRecord with Postgresql, create! results in new record as expected, with Boolean true saved as 't'

```
SiteSetting.create!(:name => :enable_github, :value => true, :data_type => 5)

=> :value => 't'
```

But when I fetch the record, change and save it, the value then changes to 0 for false or 1 for true if I set it to true again.

```
setting = SiteSetting.where(:name => :enable_github).first
setting.value = false
setting.save

=> :value => 0
```

and then

```
setting.value = true
setting.save

=> :value => 1
```

Why is the driver updating the value as an integer instead of 't' or 'f' as it should for postgresql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `value` specified as `integer` in you migration. It should be changed to `boolean`.

Comment: Ah, of course! It's actually specified as text, as it holds multiple data types depending on the setting being stored. I was thrown by the fact that it interprets the boolean as expected on create, but differently on update/save.  Not to worry, we were already explicitly setting the 't' & 'f' values. I was just curious as to the quirky behaviour.